# Connecting to .sql file from terminal on a Mac

Tags: mysql, sql, terminal

I have an unencrypted .sql file (that I can view in a text editor). The header of the file says:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (i486)
```

So I have just installed MySQL on my Mac including the command line/terminal tool, and am running the MySQL server - I would like to play around with the file in the terminal.

When I try:

> mysql file_name.sql

I get

> Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'file_name.sql'

I don't believe that I have any password/username this file. What I want to be able to do is open the .sql file, see the tables in it and then (eventually) connect to it from Python and read the tables into Pandas/Python.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong in trying to connect to the db from the command line?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a database **dump**, not a database. The file is merely a text file containing SQL instructions that'll recreate the tables, indices, views, and the data contained therein, if given to MySQL to run against a database.

You'll need to load the dump into a database before you can connect to it:

```
mysql -h hostname -u user --password=password databasename < file_name.sql
```

Here `mysql` connects to an *existing* database on hostname, with the given username and password, and loads the SQL from the file you have.

You'll need to create a database first, if you don't have one at hand to load the dump into.

Comment: on mac, you can easily export and import with `Sequel Pro` in GUI.

Comment: @zssr: sure, and there are more GUIs that can do that. They all use the same functionality offered by the MySQL API to run a SQL script.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL dump is usually a text file containing SQL commands like `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO ...` which will eventually construct the desired database for you. In order to execute these commands you will have to connect to the database server first and then (probobly also) select a database on that server.